# Run code at the end of every .cshtml render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attemting to run a small chunk of C# code at the end of every .cshtml file. I could simply just add this code in the pages themselves, however I am sure you understand that this can get very annoying to upkeep.

It is only one line of code to call a function. It calls upon a static class and it doesn't rely on any variables to be passed through to it.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of a method that I can use to call this line of code at the end of rendering each individual .cshtml file. It's not something that can be put at the end of an entire page request.

Comment: what does this call do?

Comment: @dove At the start of the view, I set some values in a static class, which are used for the functions within this static class, for this view only. At the end of view I call a function to 'reset' these values. However, not all values need to be reset, only a couple otherwise I would have gone for a non-static class approact. I could try non-static however I am worried about the future of the code due to it accessing a database to populate these fields

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. It could be an ActionFilter or some code on your layout page.

Comment: @wdosanjos these will only call the code once per page request. I need it to be per view, as though I put it at the bottom of each .cshtml file (including the layout)

Comment: these sound like shared global variables that you don't want shared.  what are you doing with these?  it's maybe not the answer you are looking for but you might want to rethink this approach

Comment: @dove I'm just making things a little easier by being able to call a single line at the top of the page to set a variable within this class, and make multiple calls to this same class to a function that relies on this variable. Rather than storing this variable in the page and passing it through each time, it would be easier to set it against the static class. However this variable can change per .cshtml file, which is the only problem otherwise I could put it at the end of my layout or call it on page completion

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple threads will be concurrently rendering .cshtml to serve multiple users.  This will cause concurrency issues in your static class.  Though you can try to workaround it by using [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: @wdosanjos I understand the dangers involved however this is only a prototype at the moment, proof of concept. Refactoring can come at a later time for this. But it seems that it isn't possible so I will have to re-address the problem from another angle